# Issue: ng-repeat with specific view should be displayed on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scenario where there are tabs and when a user clicks on the tabs then only that tab should have stars not every tab

Here is my html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs topics-div">
    <li class="li-div"><a><span>Topics</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    <li ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics">
        <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
            <p>{{topics}}</p>
            <uib-rating ng-model="rate" ng-if="displayStars" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a controler code as below:

```
$scope.fngetQList = function(topics, index) {
        debugger;
        $scope.displayQList = true;
        $scope.displayStars = true;
        $scope.sTopics = topics;
        $scope.index = index;
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList(topics).then(function(response) {
            $scope.aQuestionList = response;
            console.log($scope.aQuestionList);
        });
    };
```

Here topics is an array like `["html","css","angular"]`

The problem im facing here is when i click one tab i am getting stars for all the tabs where i need stars for only the clicked tab

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please share your fiddle or plnkr link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the tabs are getting stars because you have used the same scope variable `displayStars` in `ng-repeat`. Similarly, you will have the `rate` of all the `topics` to be the same because of the same scope variable `rate`.

Instead use an array for each of them as follows (Note that you need to know the `length` of the array `oJdDetails.topics`. So make sure your initialisations are correct.),

HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs topics-div">
    <li class="li-div"><a><span>Topics</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    <!-- use `track by $index` here along with `ng-repeat` -->
    <li ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics track by $index">
        <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="fngetQList(topics, $index)">
            <p>{{topics}}</p>
            <uib-rating ng-model="rate[$index]" ng-if="displayStars[$index]" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller code:

```
// you need to know the `length` of `oJdDetails.topics` 
$scope.rates = new Arryay(oJdDetails.topics.length).fill(0); // initialisation of array with `0` value
$scope.displayStars = new Arryay(oJdDetails.topics.length).fill(false);; // initialisation of array with `false` value
$scope.fngetQList = function (topics, index) {
    $scope.displayQList = true;
    $scope.displayStars[index] = true;
    $scope.sTopics = topics;
    $scope.index = index;
    getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList(topics).then(function(response) {
        $scope.aQuestionList = response;
        console.log($scope.aQuestionList);
    });
};
```

Hope this solves the issue.